# How do I prevent switching between items using arrows in ListBox?

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

There is a `ListBox` in which there are several `ListBoxItems`. I want to move items using the arrows (up, down, left, right). When I add one element and then select it, it moves wonderfully, but when there are several elements, it turns out that when you click the arrows, they jump from one element to another and it turns out that I start moving another element. How can I prevent switching between elements using arrows? Attaching the code:

```
<ListBox x:Name="drawing"
         Grid.Row="0"
         ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Figures}"
         SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedFigure_M}"
         SelectionMode="Single"
         Background="Transparent"
         Height="{Binding HeightDrawing}"
         Width="{Binding WidthDrawing}"
         HorizontalAlignment="Center"
         VerticalAlignment="Center"
         MouseMove="drawing_MouseMove"
         MouseLeftButtonDown="drawing_MouseLeftButtonDown"
         MouseLeftButtonUp="drawing_MouseLeftButtonUp"
         PreviewMouseWheel="drawing_MouseWheel"
         KeyDown="drawing_KeyDown"
         SelectionChanged="drawing_SelectionChanged">
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Canvas />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplateSelector>
        <local:FigureTemplateSelector EllipseTemplate="{StaticResource EllipseTemplate}"
                                      LineTemplate="{StaticResource LineTemplate}"
                                      RectangleTemplate="{StaticResource RectangleTemplate}" 
                                      TextTemplate="{StaticResource TextTemplate}"/>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplateSelector>
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Left"
                    Value="{Binding X}" />
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Top"
                    Value="{Binding Y}" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                        <Border Name="Border"
                                BorderThickness="1"
                                Padding="1">
                            <ContentPresenter Name="Content" />
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsSelected"
                                     Value="true">
                                <Setter TargetName="Border"
                                        Property="BorderBrush"
                                        Value="Transparent" />
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

I answer my own question: First, you must prohibit switching between elements using the up, down, left, and right arrows. Required in the `ListBox.ItemContainerStyle` add a `Setter`:

```
<Setter Property="KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation" Value="None" />
```

Second: Required in the `ListBox.ItemContainerStyle` add a `Setter` that disables the `IsTabStop` function:

```
<Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False" />
```

The full code will look like this:

```
<ListBox x:Name="drawing"
                                             Grid.Row="0"
                                             ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Figures}"
                                             SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedFigure_M}"
                                             SelectionMode="Single"
                                             Background="Transparent"
                                             Height="{Binding HeightDrawing}"
                                             Width="{Binding WidthDrawing}"
                                             HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                             VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                             MouseMove="drawing_MouseMove"
                                             MouseLeftButtonDown="drawing_MouseLeftButtonDown"
                                             MouseLeftButtonUp="drawing_MouseLeftButtonUp"
                                             PreviewMouseWheel="drawing_MouseWheel"
                                             KeyDown="drawing_KeyDown"
                                             SelectionChanged="drawing_SelectionChanged">
                                        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                                <Canvas />
                                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                                        <ListBox.ItemTemplateSelector>
                                            <local:FigureTemplateSelector EllipseTemplate="{StaticResource EllipseTemplate}"
                                                                          LineTemplate="{StaticResource LineTemplate}"
                                                                          RectangleTemplate="{StaticResource RectangleTemplate}" 
                                                                          TextTemplate="{StaticResource TextTemplate}"/>
                                        </ListBox.ItemTemplateSelector>
                                        <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                                            <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                                                <Setter Property="Canvas.Left"
                                                        Value="{Binding X}" />
                                                <Setter Property="Canvas.Top"
                                                        Value="{Binding Y}" />
                                                <Setter Property="Template">
                                                    <Setter.Value>
                                                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                                                            <Border Name="Border"
                                                                    BorderThickness="0.5"
                                                                    Padding="1">
                                                                <ContentPresenter Name="Content" />
                                                            </Border>
                                                            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                                                <Trigger Property="IsSelected"
                                                                         Value="true">
                                                                    <Setter TargetName="Border"
                                                                            Property="BorderBrush"
                                                                            Value="Transparent" />
                                                                </Trigger>
                                                            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                                        </ControlTemplate>
                                                    </Setter.Value>
                                                </Setter>
                                                <Setter Property="IsTabStop"
                                                        Value="False" />
                                                <Setter Property="KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation"
                                                        Value="None" />
                                            </Style>
                                        </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                                    </ListBox>
```

[Source](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c7e0f5db-b58f-4bba-89f8-f8690356b92a/keyboardnavigationdirectionalnavigation-property-has-no-effect-for-a-listbox?forum=wpf)